# Does EF4 always generate an update statement for all related entities, even when only one entity actually changed?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

.NET 4, EF 4

I have two related entities, Order and OrderLine.  Order contains (has a reference to) OrderLine.

```
Public Class Order

    Public Property OrderLine

End Class
```

There is one table for each entity in the database (order table, orderline table).  Each table has a timestamp column and the EF4 model is set up with ConcurrencyMode = Fixed for the timestamp table of each column.

I make a change to the Order, but leave the OrderLine unchanged.  When I call SaveChanges, it appears that EF4 generates an update query for the OrderLine even though nothing has changed on it.  The end result is that the timestamp for the OrderLine gets updated by the database in response to the EF4 Update command, but nothing else is updated because nothing was changed on the OrderLine.

Is this the way EF4 is supposed to handle this?  If it is, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known bug in EF4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624), you can try to contact MS for a hotfix. You can detach unmodified entities before saving, save, and then reattach the entities as a workaround. As far as I have been able to tell, it appears fixed in the Developer Preview of .NET Framework 4.5, but that is not licensed for production use.

Comment: @Casey I have been unable to find a way to request the hotfix without paying MS upfront and hoping to get it refunded, so I opted to use the workaround instead and wait for .NET 4.5.

Comment: @Casey But I am fairly certain that it will work, given that the bug does appear to actually be fixed in public preview releases.

Comment: Thanks.  You do the detach/save/reattach in your context.savechanges method?

Comment: @Casey Yes, my SaveChanges calls `GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged)`, saves all those entities in a separate list that EF does not know about, detaches them all, calls the inherited SaveChanges method, and finally reattaches all those entities. Note that this detaching and reattaching may trigger events (`Entity{Reference,Collection}.AssociationChanged`, mostly); you will have to make sure they do not cause problems for you.

Comment: Got it.  Just to make sure, I take it that EF 4.1 doesn't include the fix?

Comment: @Casey Correct, EF 4.1 is a separate library layered on top of EF 4.0. It can only add features, not fix bugs.

Comment: I have the hotfix from MS for Win 7 64 bit, working on getting it for Win XP 32 bit if you are in need of those.  Thought you might want to know. It works.

Comment: @Casey Thanks for the confirmation, and glad to know that you managed to get it.

Comment: Just in case anyone else reads this later, I was able to get the hotfix for free by entering my Visual Studio 2010 code in the MS support website and contacting them via email.

Comment: @Casey Even better: it's now possible again to request it from http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2390624&kbln=en-us -- this didn't work properly before.